# Closing programs in windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8

I've noticed that when closing programs in windows 8, that they still run in the background.

I wondered how I can get rid of this, or disable background running programs. I saw a tutorial where they would show the *win + c* side panel and it would have *permissions* section, [but when I do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAbls.jpg) the option isn't there.

So heres what I do to close a program, maybe theres a better way? a different way?

[closing program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWhJT.jpg)
and within the album is showing the program within the background.

Comment: Can you name a particular program with which you have this problem?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - you can see a few of them in the taskmanager screenshot: Mail, Store, Solitaire, Minesweeper. I think it's pretty much every app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to click on the top of the screen and drag-and-drop the app to the bottom of the screen.

Hold it down there (while keeping the mouse button pressed) for about 3 seconds until it flips over and you see the app's icon.

Release the mouse button and the app won't be suspended any more and will be terminated.

Step 1: Drag the app down to the bottom of the screen
[image]

Step 2: Wait for about 3 seconds. Release mouse button when you see the app's icon
[image]

UPDATE: Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> within the app works too

Source: [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/modernmetro-apps-still-running-on-the-background/81cc94cb-e416-4e45-95a0-f1caae2c7237)

Comment: damn, thats an annoying way of closing them. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Point mouse toward the top left or bottom left corner of the screen. When a icon of any app appears, move the mouse along your screen's left edge. A bar containing all open apps except the currently active one will appear. Right click the thumbnail and choose close to close the app.

sources:http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/view-or-close-your-open-apps-in-windows-8.html